# Text not updating correctly based on picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

This is my model

```
struct ListItemModel: Codable, Identifiable {
   let id: String  
   let name: String
}
```

This is the view that will be displayed with a Picker. The list will be populated by an outside source but I simplified it for this example.

```
struct TypeSelectionView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    
    let testList = [ListItemModel(id: "11", name: "name1"),
                        ListItemModel(id: "12", name: "name2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("Pick a Type")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< testList.count) {
                        Text(testList[$0].name)
                    }
            }.labelsHidden()
            
            Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("Pick a Type")) {
                    ForEach(testList) {type in
                        Text(type.name)
                }
            }.labelsHidden()
            
            Text("Selected Type: \(testList[selected].name)")
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}



struct TypeSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TypeSelectionView()
    }
}
```

The first Picker is correctly changing the display of the Text view on the page when the Picker changes but the second Picker does not. Is their a way to make the second Picker do the do the same thing where as you change the Picker the Text view will update accordingly
or is the first Picker the way you should always go when making Pickers in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your second `Picker` doesn't work is that the values returned by the `Picker` correspond to the `id` of the items.  In the case of your second `Picker`, those are `String`.

You can apply a `.tag()` to each item, and then the `Picker` will return that.  For example, if you added an explicit `tag` it would work:

```
Text(type.name).tag(testList.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == type.id })!)
```

Alternatively, if you changed your `id` values to be `Int` and the `id` values corresponded to the position in the array, it would work.

Because of the difficulties of implementing a `tag`, it is easy to see why many developers choose to just iterate on `0 ..< testList.count`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this my first ever answer for a stack overflow question, I'm quite a newbie myself but hopefully I can be of some help.

The code when placed in to Xcode shows two pickers whose initial values are `name1` but when you change the first picker the second picker and the text displaying the selected type change accordingly, but because both pickers share the same source of truth `@State private var selected = 0`, changing this will have unintended side effects.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TypeSelectionView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    

    @State var testList = [ListItemModel(id: "11", name: "name1"),
        ListItemModel(id: "12", name: "name2")]
    @State var priorityTypes = ["low", "medium", "high", "critical"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Pick a Type", selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(0..<testList.count) {
                    Text(self.testList[$0].name)
                }
            }.labelsHidden()

           Picker("Pick a Type", selection: $selected) {
               ForEach(0..<testList.count) {
                   Text(self.testList[$0].name)
               }
           }.labelsHidden()

            Text("Selected Type: \(testList[selected].name)")

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}



struct TypeSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TypeSelectionView()
    }
}

struct ListItemModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: The second picker is not actually there. I was just showing the two ways to display a picker that I had tried and getting clarification on why the second one did not work like intended.